# Not opening new trade position at the given level with condition

Tags: python, back-testing

Expected Behavior
open position at 3903 and take profit at 3911

Actual Behavior
open position at 3911.05 and take profit at 3911.5

Steps to Reproduce
I set buying order with a condition so it should open position when close price hit the given level and it does, but take buy position at the wrong level which is not given anywhere but one thing is there that it open order just before given tp level and close position at earliest with profit of 0.5 points only. Although as per the given code it should open position at close price i.e. 3903 when the given condition is true but instead it open position at 3911 and closing it at 3911.5. How can I resolve this problem?

```
def trade_level(self):
if self.data.close <= 3903 +1 and self.data.close >= 3903 - 1:
self.buy(sl= 3903 - 2, tp= 3903 + 9)
```

Additional info
Backtesting version: 0.3.3
`bokehJS 2.4.3:
OS: Windows 11